# Can't get into Mac Mini because it won't recognize bt keyboard and mouse and I don't have wired ones handy

Tags: bluetooth, mac-mini

I got me a new Mac mini. I am running public beta of Sonoma (maybe a big mistake :).

It won't recognize my bt keyboard (Logitech K380) and mouse (Logitech M720).

From "what I've read" it is supposed to automatically go into a pairing mode if it has no connected mouse and keyboard. And actually that happened when I set it up from scratch.

But now it doesn't seem to do it: I press the button on each remote, and hold it, until it blinks fast. Then I wait. Nothing.

Maybe I need to do something specific with my Logitech mouse and keyboard.

Is there a way for me to use an iPad or a MacBook to be the keyboard and mouse over wifi or bluetooth?

Comment: Did you try connecting the keyboard/mouse with the USB cable? That will put it into pairing mode. What brand keyboard/mouse are you using?  Is it Apple?

Comment: Unfortunately neither one has a physical usb connector. They are both fairly recent Logitech. The mouse has a usb that has a bluetooth dongle in it, so maybe I should take the dongle out and put a cable there. But they keyboard does not have any connector. Sigh. From what I have read the mac mini is supposed to go into pairing mode by itself if it doesnt have a physical keybioard and mouse. But that doesn't seem to be happening...

Comment: That’s not a BT dongle - it’s a Unifying Receiver.  You don’t need to plug that into a Mac to make things work.  Since these are not Apple peripherals, you need to pair them.  If you have the exact models of the mouse/keyboard, please [edit] your post so we can have a clearer picture.  I don’t know where you read that the Mac just goes into pairing mode like that - it would be such a security hole.

Comment: Good point about security hole. I read it "online" (reddit or stackoverflow) not anything official. Updating main description

Comment: I have a K380 (using it with my iPad right now)  and it’s BT only.  It won’t work with a Unifying Receiver.  No matter how you slice this, you need a USB keyboard or an Apple keyboard with a cable.